# How to separate the taxonomies list from the form so that editing taxonmies is the same as pages and posts?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, customization, wp-admin

Category and Taxonomy admin pages are different from posts pages in that the items are listed and the form is also present on the same page.  I would like to separate them for custom taxonomies so that the items are listed on a separate page than the form itself, just as posts and pages are.

The reason for this is I have a load of custom fields attached to the taxonomies and the pages are very messy and not user friendly when squashed onto half the page.

I have amended the CSS to hide the form and expand the list to fill the page and this works fine apart from the fact that the user can now only edit an existing taxonomy and not add a new as the new form has been hidden.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Many thanks

Comment: There's no simple answer. You're going to have to set `show_ui` of your taxonomy to `false`, add your own admin page with `add_submenu_page()` and then build the taxonomy UI completely from scratch.

Comment: There must be a better way, I mean I have it almost working how I want already apart from the the ability to be able to add a new term